# Why is the following matrix product inequality true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose that $A$ is a non-singular square matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. I read a paper that used the following inequality

$$ADA^{-1} A^{-\ast}D^\ast A^\ast \succeq \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast}) ADD^\ast A^\ast$$

Why is this inequality true? I understand that $A^{-1} A^{-\ast} \succeq \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast})I$ but how exactly does this result in the above inequality?

Comment: What is $A^{-*}$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That typically denotes $(A^{-1})^*$ (equivalently $(A^{-1})^*$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
A^{-1} A^{-\ast} \succeq \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast})I \implies\\
A^{-1} A^{-\ast} - \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast})I \succeq 0 \implies \\
AD(A^{-1} A^{-\ast} - \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast})I)D^*A^* \succeq 0 \implies\\
AD(A^{-1} A^{-\ast})D^*A^* 
\succeq 
AD(\lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast})I)D^*A^* 
\implies \\
ADA^{-1} A^{-\ast}D^\ast A^\ast \succeq \lambda_\min(A^{-1}A^{-\ast}) \cdot ADD^\ast A^\ast
$$
as was desired.